Topological degree of a continuous mapping
I am discovering the topological degree and while I can see why it’s construction is legit for smooth map $f : M\to N$ where $N$ and $M$ are differentiable manifolds, the later being compact. I cannot see how to extend it to continuous function.
Indeed, from my book (Milnor’s book Topology from the differentiable viewpoint) the construction is realized for regular values $y$ in order to use the inverse function theorem to ensure that the degree is well defined (i.e finite).
For a continuous function $f$ this is no more possible. However I find a lot of papers where the degree is used for continuous mapping
I would like to have some insights on how to proceed to extend this notion for continuous function please or some ressources dealing with a complete construction of the degree for continuous mapping please.
Thank you a lot !


You should require manifolds to have the same dimension. 2. Do you know that every continuous map is homotopic to a smooth one and that degree of smooth maps is preserved by homotopy? 3. If you want to see a definition of degree for maps of topological manifolds you have to learn some algebraic topology. See for instance Hatcher's book.


@MoisheKohan Thank you a lot for your comment ! The point $2$ is the key : I was aware of the homotopy invariance but not of the fact that every continuous map is homotopic to à smooth one ! Thanks for the revommandation !
